# How to make the Signpost visible on mouse hover?

Tags: vmware-clarity

Is there a way to show the signpost when hovering an element? For example, if I hover on the icon, the signpost should show up. I'm not into accessibility requirements, I just want to trigger it when hovering.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got working now. So I just need to use the [(clrIfOpen)] and bind it to a variable. Then I just have to add a mouseenter and a mouseleave event to the icon that set the variable to true or false.